# incremental Shiny UI using conditionalPanel() and a text output in conditions

Tags: r, shiny

I have been trying to create a Shiny UI that changes depending on the stage of data processing, but I can't figure out why my conditional panels don't pop up, and why even my text output for debugging doesn't show a value in the UI.

In this small example, I want to be able to show a panel after pressing a button, and then another one after pressing the second button. If the user presses the first button again, the second panel should disappear.

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    p("value of stage is:"),
    textOutput("stage"),
    actionButton("button1", "Show only the first panel"),
    conditionalPanel("output.stage == 'first' || output.stage == 'second'",
                     p("First panel."),
                     actionButton("button2", "Also show the second panel")),
    conditionalPanel("output.stage == 'second'",
                     p("Second panel."))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  stage <- reactive({"initial"})
  stage <- eventReactive(input$button1, {"first"})
  stage <- eventReactive(input$button2, {"second"})
  output$stage <- renderText({stage()})
  # make stage always available to UI
  outputOptions(output, "stage", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I also tried using `observeEvent()` but that didn't help.

**Edit**: I am not directly using the `input.button*` values in my conditions because in my use case, the `stage` value also depends on other things happening on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT for better explanation :

You are defining `stage` too many times. The only one counting is the last one :

```
stage <- eventReactive(input$button2, {"second"})
```

At this point, `stage` is only that, so it never triggers.

Here is what you are searching for :

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  p("value of stage is:"),
  textOutput("stage"),
  actionButton("button1", "Show only the first panel"),
  conditionalPanel("output.stage == 'first' || output.stage == 'second'",
                   p("First panel."),
                   actionButton("button2", "Also show the second panel")),
  conditionalPanel("output.stage == 'second'",
                   p("Second panel.")),
  textOutput("stage_dependant")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  button1_triggered <- reactiveVal(F)
  button2_triggered <- reactiveVal(F)
  
  observeEvent(input$button1,{
    button1_triggered(!button1_triggered()) ## assigning a new value to button1_triggered : its contrary
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$button2,{
    button2_triggered(!button2_triggered()) ## Invert the boolean
  })

  stage <- reactive({
    if(!button1_triggered() & !button2_triggered()){
      "intial"
    } else if(button1_triggered() & !button2_triggered()){
      "first"
    } else if(!button1_triggered() & button2_triggered()){
      "second anyways ?"
    } else {
      "second"
    }
  })
  
  output$stage <- renderText({stage()})
  # make stage always available to UI
  outputOptions(output, "stage", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)

stage_dependant <- reactive({
        paste("This is a stage dependant reactive :",stage())
      })
    
      output$stage_dependant <- renderText(stage_dependant())
}



  

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

You can search for more elegant ways to define `stage` but with this you should understand the principle.

Also note that the use of `checkboxInput` seems to be more appropriate for this functionnality.

Comment: Thank you Levon! Following up:
- How come only the last `stage` assignment is "the only one counting", even though its reactiveness depends on something different to the others? Is that a Shiny thing that objects can only be defined with one single statement?
- Your solution doesn't hide the second panel when pressing the first button again. Any idea how to add that in?

Comment: Okay, I am realising I didn't really understood what you were looking for. Editing again...

Comment: Like every other objects, you can make an assignment on it only once. Every succeding assignments will overwrite the precedent one. Reactive objects does not differ.

However, which differs with reactiveness is that it triggers when an input (or another input dependent object) changes in its expression. For instance, reactive({input$some_numeric + 1}) will make {input$some_numeric + 1} reevaluated every time input$some_numeric changes.

Same with reactive({some_numeric() + 1}) assessing some_numeric is also reactive.

Comment: In my answer, the idea is the exact same but the syntax is a bit different. The only difference is that I needed to add a base value.
False is assigned to "button1_triggered" (False = hidden) as a base value, which is inverted every time you click on the button.

Comment: I added some outputs in your example to make it clear !

Comment: and sorry for the misunderstanding, my english is a bit rusty lol

Comment: fabulous, thank you for the extra help! I think that this combination of `observeEvent()` and `reactiveVal()` is what I was after.